# migrating to coffeescript from javascript and proper using of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am quite new to coffeescript, although I want to learn in order to optimize my workflow in the future.

The problem is that I am missing out some concepts, for example

```
var foo = {
    init: function() {
        this.ui.build();
        this.bindEvents(); 
    },
    bindEvents: function() {}
    ...
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    foo.init();
})
```

translated like this in coffeescript

```
foo = 
  init: ->
    @.ui.build();
    @.bindEvents();
  bindEvents: ->
  ...
  ...

$('document').ready(->
   foo.init();
)
```

What did I do wrong? What are your suggestions in my way of creating objects?

Comment: What makes you think you did something wrong?

Comment: because it says foo is not defined.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsbin.com/ipugin/1/edit/. Maybe the problem is in the code you didn't code.

Comment: Are your `foo = ...` and `$(document).ready(...)` in different files?

Comment: i got a problem in my code, my bad.. but the answer below suffice to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coffescript allows you to define classes.

```
class Foo
    constructor: ->
      @ui.build()
      @bindEvents()
    bindEvents: ->
    ...
    ...



$('document').ready () ->
   foo = new Foo
```

You shouldnt use `@.field` notation. Use `@field` instead.